# Coded UI - How can I assert a date field (combo box) which is changing name dynamically?

Tags: automated-testing, coded-ui-tests, desktop-application

I am making automation for Desktop .net application. one of the challanges i am facing is date combo box which is name changing everyday

[image]

[image]

**uIItem22Ağustos2016PazDropDown** part changing everyday...

Above i gave you the part of the interface and the code generated in background

Answer (score 1):

Talk to developers to give the item permanent id.

Not sure why name is changing, in my experience ID is usually dynamic, generated by framework and name is left alone.

If you cannot get permanent ID, or name, try adding CSS class (and locate element by class). Or use CSS-style locators.

Failing that, you are in for a world of pain: forever-flaky XPath. :-(